# Jquery image gallery issue in expression engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, expressionengine

I have a slight problem with a javascript plugin i have integrated into expression engine (EE). I'm not sure whether its a CSS/HTML problem or something being overwritten in EE. I using the plug jqzoom, which i've managed to integrate fine on my static site However on my EE site [click here](http://www.iamnatesmithen.com/ExpressionEngine2/index.php/inventory/view/VPREP-BRAVO-COMPATIBLE-ROBOTIC-TIPS) the secondary image is not displaying (none) and is over lapping the primary. Initial set up of this plugin mean't to work like the following [click here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/fluotics/productsFinal.html) - you click on the thumbnail the image changes etc... does anyone know what's causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

in your [first link](http://www.iamnatesmithen.com/ExpressionEngine2/index.php/inventory/view/VPREP-BRAVO-COMPATIBLE-ROBOTIC-TIPS) I saw two images are already in a div with a class clearfix. But in the second one there is only one. I think somehow you messed up with the images in the first one. Try to look in the code where you entered the image source in the website you mentioned in [first link](http://www.iamnatesmithen.com/ExpressionEngine2/index.php/inventory/view/VPREP-BRAVO-COMPATIBLE-ROBOTIC-TIPS)